# Strange errors using factory_boy and DjangoModelFactory

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, factory-boy

I've created several factories including a user factory that looks like so

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        django_get_or_create = ('phonenumber',)

    uuid = factory.Faker('uuid4')
    email = factory.Faker('email')
    phonenumber = factory.Sequence(generate_phone_number)
```

I'm using the django unit test TestCase model like so

```
class ApiV1TestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = UserFactory.create()
```

and getting the following error: `*** django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_user_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.`

when I run it several times I get a continual error with what looks like a correctly autoincremented ID field, ie. `Key (id)=(2) already exists.` ... `Key (id)=(3) already exists.` on each subsequent create() call.

If I check the test database, I see that `User.objects.all()` is empty in all of these cases.

Alternatively I'm able to successfully run

```
UserFactory.build()
u.save()
```

however this isn't great for obvious reasons (ie. I want to override an `auto_now` datetime field in some tests)

I've also noticed some strange behavior, if I check `transaction.get_connection().in_atomic_block`  from `django.db.transaction` I get `True` which seems to indicate somehow that I'm in an atomic block? I'm not sure if this is normal behavior.

Comment: The `transaction.get_connection().in_atomic_block` is normal behaviour from Django's `TestCase` for faster tests, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#testcase for some details. It enables Django to ensure different tests within a class are truly independant.

Comment: that's really great to know, how did you learn that? I was always under the impression that TransactionTestCase would do that but I had it reversed.

Answer (score 1):

So after some debugging, I figured out that there was a `save()` method override that did something somewhat strange

Some users will call the save() method twice, someone did this in our codebase, the code looks like so :

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.email:
        self.email = None
    # validate_password(self._password)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    if not self.batch_group:
        self.batch_group = self.id % 432

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

for some reason this causes errors with `factory_boy`